# How to generate the predicted labels in Caffe through the CLI?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I trained a neural network model using Caffe:

```
/home/f/caffe-master/build/tools/caffe train -solver=/media/my_solver.prototxt
```

I then scored the learned model on the validation set:

```
/home/f/caffe-master/build/tools/caffe test -model=/media/my_train_test.prototxt 
                                            -weights model.caffemodel -iterations 100
```

But how to get the labels predicted by the trained neural network model in Caffe?

---

I know I can use the Python or Matlab bindings for that purpose, but I am curious to know whether we can get the predicted labels in Caffe directly through the command line interface.

It does not seem to be mentioned in the [official Caffe's tutorial on interfaces](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/interfaces.html), and looking at  `caffe`'s help didn't help:

```
> f@f-VirtualBox:~/caffe/caffe-master/build/tools$ ./caffe
caffe: command line brew
usage: caffe <command> <args>

commands:
  train           train or finetune a model
  test            score a model
  device_query    show GPU diagnostic information
  time            benchmark model execution time

  Flags from /home/f/caffe-master/tools/caffe.cpp:
    -gpu (Run in GPU mode on given device ID.) type: int32 default: -1
    -iterations (The number of iterations to run.) type: int32 default: 50
    -model (The model definition protocol buffer text file..) type: string
      default: ""
    -snapshot (Optional; the snapshot solver state to resume training.)
      type: string default: ""
    -solver (The solver definition protocol buffer text file.) type: string
      default: ""
    -weights (Optional; the pretrained weights to initialize finetuning. Cannot
      be set simultaneously with snapshot.) type: string default: ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to go through Python, you can add a [HDF5_OUTPUT](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/docs/tutorial/layers.md#hdf5-output) layer: it will save the predicted outputs in an HDF5 file.

Otherwise if you feel like going in the code, you could print or save `bottom_data_vector[k].second` at around https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.cpp#L74